# Не отображается маршрутизация в react-yandex-maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

**Проблема заключается в следующем:** Не отображаются маршруты между точками, может я как-то не так пытаюсь добавить multiRoute в geoObjects, не могу понять. 
Загружаю сразу все пакеты в load: 'package.full', API верный, в консоли ни на что не ругается. 
Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.
Вот код компонента:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'

// Components
import { Dialog } from '../../components/Dialog'
import { Map, YMaps } from '@pbe/react-yandex-maps'

// Types
import { type SlotsItem } from './types'

const API_KEY = import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY

interface MapDialogProps {
    data: SlotsItem[] | undefined
}

export function MapDialog({ data }: MapDialogProps) {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(true)
    const map = useRef<any>(null)

    const createRoutes = (ymaps: any) => {
        const pointA = [55.749, 37.524]
        const pointB = ['Москва, Красная площадь']

        const multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute(
            {
                referencePoints: [pointA, pointB],
                params: {
                    routingMode: 'pedestrian',
                },
            },
            {
                boundsAutoApply: true,
            }
        )
        map.current.geoObjects.add(multiRoute)
    }

    return (
        <Dialog open={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)} fullScreen>
            <YMaps
                query={{
                    lang: 'ru_RU',
                    apikey: API_KEY,
                    load: 'package.full',
                }}
            >
                <Map
                    defaultState={{
                        center: [55.749, 37.524],
                        zoom: 12,
                    }}
                    instanceRef={map}
                    width={'100%'}
                    height={'100%'}
                    onLoad={createRoutes}
                />
            </YMaps>
            )
        </Dialog>
    )
}
```